# How to check whether a VARCHAR column contains a substring of string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Given a `mainstring`, How can I check that a column, `c`, in my database, contains **substring of given string**?

statement like `...c LIKE %mainstring%` won't do the work because it will check if `mainstring` itself is a substring of `c`. I want to check whether a substring of `mainstring` is a substring of `c`.

How can I achieve that in `sql`?

EDIT:
Given `mainstring` consists of words separated by `' '` I want to check if `c` contains any of these words (complete word) - at least one of them.

Comment: Define substring.

Comment: No idea how long your strings are but I would write a procedure to check all substring s of `mainstring` against all substrings of current column `c`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's strpos equivalent in sql ;-)

Comment: For your case, `Find_in_set` looks useful.